# MySQL Server version different than MySQL version PHP is reporting

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm running Wordpress on a RHEL 5 box. PHP is version 5.3.3, and we just upgraded the MySQL server on the box to 5.5.32 (up from 5.0.xx).

It seems like that upgrade went well, and Wordpress is running just fine. But what I don't understand is that PHP is continuing to report that it is using MySQL 5.0.95.

Anyone have a clue how I can tell PHP to use MySQL 5.5?

Comment: Where is PHP "reporting" MySQL 5.0.95?

Comment: PHP is using 5.0.95 of the MySQL client library. PHP will not report on the version of MySQL being used on the MySQL server. You can update your mysql client library on your PHP machine. Or better yet, you may consider we compiling PHP with the MySQL Native Driver enabled, which will decouple you from having to have MySQL client library on your machine at all.  More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.overview.php

Comment: I'm seeing that when I run the phpinfo() script.

Comment: Also, mysql -V reports:
 mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: And what does `phpinfo()` say?  "**Client API version**"?  As @MikeBrant points out, that is not the *server version*.

Comment: @MikeBrant - thanks. So I need to get PHP to use 5.5 of the MySQL client library? Can you point me in the right direction on how to do that?

Comment: Yep - from phpinfo()- 
Client API version 5.0.95

Comment: Upgrading is most likely optional. 5.x client vs. 5.x server should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just making my comment into answer as I added to it, it became more complete.

PHP is using 5.0.95 of the MySQL client library. PHP will not report on the version of MySQL being used on the MySQL server.

You can update your mysql client library on your PHP machine. Or better yet, you may consider re-compiling PHP with the MySQL Native Driver enabled, which will decouple you from having to have MySQL client library on your machine at all.

More info on MySQL native driver: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.overview.php

If you just want to upgrade your MySQL client package on RHEL 5, use RPM.  I am not sure what the most recent rpm package for mysql client is named for RHEL 5, but the command would be something like this:

```
rpm -Uvh mysql-clientXXXX.rpm
```

Comment: Okay - good. This gives me something to attempt. Thanks - I'll report back after I give this a run. Thanks!

Comment: @HalAtkins Just edited to add commentary on package upgrade based on your comment above.